# How to open new web page in a tab In IE 8 in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hi Experts
How I can open several URL in tabs in IE 8 using c#?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you get your hands on the IWebBrowser2 interface of the webbrowser object, then use the [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. Passing *navOpenInNewTab* in the flags will open the navigated URL in a separate tab.

Pitfalls: do not mix with other flags, do not mix with headers and/or postdata.

Comment: Is It possible to use IE active X and use Navigate method to open several URL in application?not open externally?

Answer (score 3):

There is no guaranteed way to control that a new window that you open will be opened up  specifically as a new tab. This is because most browsers have this control as a user defined setting.

As far as i can remember, when using `window.open` in javascript, the best you can do is use `target = '_blank'` to specify that the target will always be opened in a new window. However, whether this new window is in fact just a new tab or an actual new window is controlled by the users browser setting in tabbed browsers

Comment: To me, the way Nima posted the question suggests there is more direct control over the browser than from a javascript environment. I'm not aware of IE ever ignoring the navOpenInNewTab flag, whatever the user settings are.